# How to reconnect to a server after the server stopped serving request in Netty IO

Tags: java, server, io, client, netty

My netty IO client should keep trying to connect to a server whenever the server is restarted or the existing connection is broken. To implement this my client creates a new thread for establishing a new connection whenever the ChannelInActive callback method of my ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter is invoked. But my client throws the below error while establishing a new connection.

> Exception in thread "main" io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:8888
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>       ... 11 more

Below lines are the run part of my connection thread.

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(group);
bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new 
ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws 
Exception {
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new 
LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64 * 1024, 0, 2));
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(ClientHandler);
        }

    });
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR,true);
    ChannelFuture channelFuture=null;
try 
{
    channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP, 
port)).sync();      
    channelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
    channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture)
         {
        try
        {
            if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
            if(connectfuture!=null) connectfuture.cancel(true);log.debug("Cancelled connection thread scheduler");

        } else {
            channelFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
        connectfuture=channelFuture.channel().eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(new ClientConnectorThread(ClientHandler,IP,port) , 5,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        } );

}

catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want to implement re-connection logic, I do it as follows

Add two handlers for pipeline for capturing idle state

```
pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
pipeline.addLast("ReconnectionHandler", new ReconnectionHandler());
```

In `ReconnectionHandler` capture the user event fired by `ReadTimeoutHandler`, disconnect the channel and try to reconnect

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if (e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    } else {
        ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(evt);
    }
}

public void channelUnregistered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    final EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = ctx.channel().eventLoop().parent();
    eventLoopGroup.schedule(() -> {
        bootstrap.connect()
    }, reconnectDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ctx.fireChannelUnregistered();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! As you have mentioned I have a handler(SimpleChannelInboundHandler) added to my pipeline which has a callback method named "channelInactive". So once the server is closing the connection this method is correctly called but when I try to create a connection using bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP,Port)) method I get the said error lines.

Comment: if that's the case you need to figure out first whether the server is listening on the port or not. Telnet to the port when said exception fires. If you can't telnet the fault is on the server not the client.